# Embedding a ring into a field or skew -field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Milnor's K-theory book states the following:

> Suppose that $R$  (a unital ring) can be mapped homomorphically into a field or skew-field $F$. This is always possible, if for example, $R$ is commutative.

My question is, if $R$ has no zero divisors, this is attained via the quotient field. However, if there are zero divisors, or if the ring is not commutative, when is it possible to do so?

Comment: Note that the homomorphism is not guaranteed to be injective. For a commutative ring we can take a quotient by a maximal ideal. I'm not sure what can be said in general for noncommutative rings though.

Comment: If $R$ is commutative and $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal then $R \to R/\mathfrak p \to q(R/\mathfrak p)$, where $q(R/\mathfrak p)$ is the quotient field of $R/\mathfrak p$ is such a homomorphism. Thus, every prime ideal gives rise to a homomorphism into a field. The noncommutative situtation is considerably more difficult; I don't believe a full description is possible (not every noncommutative domain has to embed into a skew-field). But, for instance, if $R/\mathfrak p$ is Ore, then one can construct a (classical) skew field of fractions of $R/\mathfrak p$ and the same argument goes through.

Comment: I think there is plenty of work on domains embedding into skew fields; amongst others by P.M. Cohn. You may want to skim through his books.For instance, free algebras over fields embed into skew fields, even though they are not Ore domains.